# SwitchRender.SwitchRender()' is obsolete with Xamarin.Forms renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am implementing code for SwitchRenderer in Android but it appears that there is an issue with the code as I get a warning:

> 'SwitchRender.SwitchRender()' is obsolete; 'This constuctor is
>   obsolets as of version 2.5. Please use SwitchRender(Context) instead.'

Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this problem:

```
using Japanese.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Japanese;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtSwitch), typeof(ExtSwitchRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.Android
{
    public class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        private ExtSwitch view;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;
            view = (ExtSwitch)Element;
            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)
            {
                if (this.Control != null)
                {
                    if (this.Control.Checked)
                    {
                        this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    }
                    this.Control.CheckedChange += this.OnCheckedChange;
                    UpdateSwitchThumbImage(view);
                }
                //Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchBGColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);  
            }
        }

        private void UpdateSwitchThumbImage(CustomSwitch view)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.SwitchThumbImage))
            {
                view.SwitchThumbImage = view.SwitchThumbImage.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");
                int imgid = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(view.SwitchThumbImage).GetValue(null);
                Control.SetThumbResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
            }
            else
            {
                Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchThumbColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
                // Control.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.track);  
            }
        }

        private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Control.Checked)
            {
                this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            this.Control.CheckedChange -= this.OnCheckedChange;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/307440/#Comment_307440). The new way to do Android custom renderers would be this:

```
public class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    private ExtSwitch view;

    public ExtSwitchRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    ....
}
```

Then if you actually need to use the Android context in your custom renderer, you would use the one passed in through the constructor, instead of `Forms.Context` for example.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed !